# Match any patterns in a table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I know we can use LIKE for pattern matching, however, here is what want to do.

I have a table, which has a column, 'Pattern', the values are like:

```
host1%
%host2
....
```

I have another table, which has a column, 'Host'. The question is: how can I check whether the values in 'Host' table do not match any patterns in 'Pattern'?

If it is too complex, then a simplified question is: How can I check whether the values in 'Host' do not StartWith any strings in 'Pattern'?

We can use loop, but is there a better way? ideally, it should work for ql server 2008, but latest version will do.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `where not exists` followed by a subquery which checks each pattern against the current row of the table containing your data.  i.e.

```
where not exists 
(
    select top 1 1
    from @patterns p
    where d.datum like p.pattern
)
```

Full Code for Working Example: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7d/1237)

```
declare @patterns table 
(
    pattern nvarchar(16) not null
)
declare @data table
(
    datum nvarchar(16) not null
)
insert @patterns
values ('host1%')
,('%host2')
insert @data
values ('host1234')
, ('234host1')
, ('host2345')
, ('345host2')

select *
from @data d
where not exists 
(
    select top 1 1
    from @patterns p
    where d.datum like p.pattern
)
```

Comment: it would help to have aliases

Comment: @Bulat; good shout; just be being lazy; now amended with aliases for improved clarity.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.host
from table_1 t1
left join table_2 t2 on t1.host like t2.pattern
where t2.pattern is null
```